# MYSQL inserting wrong info

Tags: mysql

I am inserting value

```
insert into user (name,fbid) Values ('Adi Mathur',100000564553314)
```

but in the database i see the value if fbid to be

> 2147483647

Why ? How should i fix it ?

> fbid  int(50)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html), the maximum value of a (signed) `INT`, which occupies 4 bytes/32 bits, is 2,147,483,647; for integer data types, the [number in parenthesis](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-types.html) is the display width, which only affects the way that the data is displayed, not how much space it is allocated for storage:

> `M` indicates the maximum display width for integer types. For floating-point and fixed-point types, `M` is the total number of digits that can be stored (the precision). For string types, `M` is the maximum length. The maximum permissible value of M depends on the data type.

You probably want a `BIGINT`.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: He might need something even bigger, depending on what other data that column is intended to hold.